# Get position of scrolled div and detect which element is scrolled to

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-chrome

I want to build a little module with react. Inside that module I have a scrollable element with

```
scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(40px);
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
```

so it stick to the one of elements of the list. I need to know which element is currently at the center (selected). Currently I get `scrollTop` of element and divide it by 50 (40px plus margins 5px). But it only works in safari. In chrome value when it snaps to one of element scrollTop value is 47 per element and it changes with scaling. On 20+ elements this error is enough to choose previous element if I round values. Is there a way to get size of element to divide by. Or maybe I can get currently selected element in another way.
Also I don't want any dependencies in my code since it almost done and i didn't have any besides react itself.

Comment: Can you assign a ref to the selected element and get its ref.current.getClientRects(), you'll have its coords from that .  Just an idea

Comment: @dorriz, I get current.firstChild.getClientRects() and it returned height 40 in safari and 38 in chrome (but that is without margins I guess). If margins doesn't get distorted it may work. Thanks. (I will answer my question if it works out)

Comment: Great! If you get a solution be sure to post it to help someone else. Keep going keep learning !

Comment: Did you look at Intersection Observer as an option? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API